# get local android test resources

Tags: java, android, junit, resources

When running standard junit tests (not AndroidTestCase) in Android, how can I get resources in **src/test/resources**?

I have tried all the usual...

> `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/testData.dat");`

and...

> `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
>       .getResourceAsStream("/testData.dat");`

and also with gradle copy resources..

> task copyTestResources(type: Copy) {
>       from "${projectDir}/src/test/resources"
>       into "${buildDir}/classes/test" }

What confuses me is when I ask in the unit test what the classloaders path is for getting resources using

> ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
>           URL resource = classLoader.getResource(".");

It returns:  **/home/rob/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-17/data/res**

Can anyone please explain this to me and tell me how I can get a relative path anywhere in the project so I can use test resources?